# Javascript Coding -> Button Changes and Pause Marquee

Tags: javascript

I am running this link

My Current problem is,

1) The marquee will display the whole bunch of text, auto marquee from down to top.

2) I would like to add in a button, which functions as stop scroll-marquee and resume - and i have that in my page. but it is not feasible as it had two buttons. To make it more efficient, i decided to add in a javascrip button, which changes text once it is clicked.

3) I have tried my very best to modify, but it dosnt work. Can anyone help me to correct this simple snippets ?

Thanks
-John

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" style="height:500px;" scrollamount="6" id="mymarquee" ><?php echo $price_today; ?></marquee>

<input type="button" value="Stop Marquee" onClick="document.getElementById('mymarquee').stop();" / >
<input type="button" value="Start Marquee" onClick="document.getElementById('mymarquee').start();" / > 
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Pause Autoscroll" id="myButton1" />


<script type="text/javascript">

  function change() // no ';' here
    {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    if (elem.value=="Pause Autoscroll") 
        elem.value = "Continue Autoscroll";
        document.getElementById('mymarquee').stop();
    else 
        elem.value = "Pause Autoscroll";
        document.getElementById('mymarquee').start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not embrace the `if` and `else` statements in curly braces, that's a simple syntax issue rather than anything else.

```js
 var change = function() // no ';' here
    {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    if (elem.value=="Pause Autoscroll") {
        elem.value = "Continue Autoscroll";
        document.getElementById('mymarquee').stop();
        }
    else {
        elem.value = "Pause Autoscroll";
        document.getElementById('mymarquee').start();
        }
    }
```

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" style="height:500px;" scrollamount="6" id="mymarquee" >$799</marquee>

<input type="button" value="Stop Marquee" onClick="document.getElementById('mymarquee').stop();" / >
<input type="button" value="Start Marquee" onClick="document.getElementById('mymarquee').start();" / > 
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Pause Autoscroll" id="myButton1" />
```

Comment: Glad to help. If it answered your question, you can accept it as an answer so that the other people, who run into this in the future, would know what this answer works.
P.S.: It must be a good 10 years since I've seen the <marquee> tag, your brought back so many memories :)

Comment: actually i wanted to close the thread, but i cant find the close or answered button. i am really new into this

Comment: You would see a faded-out tick next to the answer, when you tick it it becomes green and that means an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

your if else statement needs {}

```
function change() // no ';' here
{
   var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
   if (elem.value=="Pause Autoscroll"){
      elem.value = "Continue Autoscroll";
      document.getElementById('mymarquee').stop();
   }else{ 
      elem.value = "Pause Autoscroll";
      document.getElementById('mymarquee').start();
   }
}
```